# Error en la linea de package de mis clases y en esta linea de mi manifests " <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> "

Tags: android, android-studio

Estaba trabajando en un ejemplo Android, en el cual primero me marcaba un error en la libreria:

> compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'

Se soluciono subiendo la versión a targetSdkVersion 25 y compileSdkVersion 25, anteriormente estaban en versión 24.

Bueno todo muy bien solo que ahora tengo un nuevo error,  el error se encuentra en las clases, mas especifico en la linea donde se declara el package, dicho error me deja compilar el programa, pero al momento de tratar de instalar el apk, la aplicación falla y el celular me lanza el siguiente mensaje:

***Se produjo un error durante el análisis del paquete.***

Aquí abajo dejo las lineas donde me sale el error:

En esta linea en todas las clases me sale el siguiente error--->

> package com.example.jorge.chatapp;

Dicho error dice:  the sdk platform-tools version (24.0.4) is too old to check apis compiled with api 25; please update

En esta linea del manifests me sale el error

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Dicho error dice:  the sdk platform-tools version (24.0.4) is too old to check apis compiled with api 25; please update

**Este es mi manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**este es mi app/build.gradle**

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jorge.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       //Add Library
       compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**este es mi Project/build.gradle**

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'




        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Y por dejar el ejemplo de una clase con el error**

```html
package com.example.jorge.chatapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

***Para ejemplificar un poco mas dejo algunas imágenes***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si revisas el mensaje:

> The SDK platform-tools version (24.0.4 rc1) is too old to check APIs
>   compiled with API 25; please update

indica que es necesaria una actualización de `Android SDK Platform-tools` debido a que tienes definido un `targetSdkVersion` a la api 25.

```
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Actualiza!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente Gracias Elenasys!

Answer (score 3):

Amigos ya resolví mi problema lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

Seguí la siguiente ruta...

SDK Manager ---> SDK Tools ---> Aquí se vera una actualización disponible del SDK platforms-Tools, solo se tiene que actualizar y listo!

Y sobre lo de que se me cerraba la aplicación era por que tenia una versión "minSdkVersion 22" y lo estaba instalando en un celular que soportaba "minSdkVersion 16" lo que hice solo fue bajarlo a 16, y eso era todo funciono perfecto después.